# Select rows that do NOT have a DISTINCT value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can someone suggest a method for selecting rows that do not have a unique value for a column?

If I have five records, with 1 record that has CustNo = 7, 1 record that has CustNo = 9, and three records that have CustNo = 11, I only want to select the three rows that have CustNo = 11

Comment: For future reference, it is easier to give you a helpful answer if you provide the schema of your table, as well as what you have already tried.

Comment: NB: for the answers below, they are not handling a `NULL` CustNo... but its probably fairly safe to assume that would not happen in most cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to display all the rows which are not distinct you need to have a sub query like this

```
select * from CustDetails
WHERE CustNo IN (SELECT CustNo from CustDetails 
                 group by CustNo 
                 having count(CustNo) > 1)
```

here is the sql fiddle for the same

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c9a4/4

Comment: CustDetails could contain more than 1 column resulting in an error with `IN`. (since IN expects only one column)

Comment: @SimchaKhabinsky well that was not mentioned in the question.. I have edited the answer now

Answer (score 4):

This will find records, and count of them, that have duplicates in CustNo

```
Select CustNo, Count(*) From Table1
Group By CustNo
Having Count(*) > 1
```

And another way for full solution (get full record of only those that have duplicates), using group and join

```
Select t1.*
From Table1  t1 inner join 
    (Select CustNo cn From Table1
     Group By CustNo
     Having Count(*) > 1) t2 On t1.CustNo = t2.cn
```

Answer (score 3):

This retrieves all duplicate records:

```
SELECT CustNo FROM MyTable Group By CustNo Having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: I need the whole row.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just doing a `SELECT/GROUP BY` will return only one row for the records where CustNo is non-unique.  Implementing that in a sub-query however, should do it.

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then this will return the rows in `CustomerTable` where CustNo is not unique:

```
SELECT *
FROM CustomerTable
WHERE CustNo IN (
    SELECT CustNo
    FROM CustomerTable
    GROUP BY CustNo
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: That's the ticket.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the complete rows for rows that are duplicates, then use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by CustNo) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```